# How to use json server with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, json-server

I've installed json-server by using:

```
npm install -g json-server
```

then I created a db.json like this:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Sebastian",
      "last_name": "Eschweiler",
      "email": "sebastian@codingthesmartway.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Steve",
      "last_name": "Palmer",
      "email": "steve@codingthesmartway.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "Ann",
      "last_name": "Smith",
      "email": "ann@codingthesmartway.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

I watch json-server by:

```
json-server --watch db.json
```

but it does not work. The message in terminal is:

> cannot be loaded because running  scripts is disabled on  this system.
>   For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
>   https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

What happened?

Comment: If you go to the link and enable this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7

Comment: how to enable? Can you help me?

Comment: i'm seted :
 Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine -> A .
But not work it message: is denied. To change the execution
policy for the default (LocalMachine) scope, start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option. To
change the execution policy for the current user, run "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser"

Answer (score 1):

You can install json-server as a dev dependency

```
npm install -D json-server
```

then you can run the below command

```
npx json-server --watch db.json --port 3004
```

It will work.

Comment: I already had a global install of json-server (I didn't use the `-D` flag) and was having trouble running the `json-server` command in Visual Studio Code's terminal, but running the `npx` command worked.